# Import scraped data from website directly into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I want to import web-scraped data directly into PostgreSQL, without exporting it to .csv in the first place.

Here's the code I'm using, to export data to .csv file, then I'm importing it manually. Any help would be appreciated

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page1_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#html parsing
page1_soup = soup(page1_html,"html.parser")

filename = "TollDetail12.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "ID, tollname, location, highwayNumber\n"
f.write(headers)

#grabing data
containers = page1_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"PA15"})
for container in containers:
    toll_name = container.p.b.text

    search1 = container.findAll('b')
    highway_number = search1[1].text

    location = list(container.p.descendants)[10]
    ID = my_url[my_url.find("?"):]
    mystr = ID.strip("?")
    print("ID: " + mystr)
    print("toll_name: " + toll_name)
    print("location: " + location)
    print("highway_number: " + highway_number)
        

    f.write(mystr + "," + toll_name + "," + location + "," + highway_number.replace(",","|") + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: [insert in data into postgresql](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/insert/) read this. It will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `psycopg2` pip package. Apart from that, edit file with your project-specific informations, haven't tested but should work.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import psycopg2

my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page1_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
# html parsing
page1_soup = soup(page1_html, 'html.parser')

# grabing data
containers = page1_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'PA15'})

# Make the connection to PostgreSQL
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='database_name',
                        user='user_name', password='user_password', port=5432)
cursor = conn.cursor()
for container in containers:
    toll_name = container.p.b.text

    search1 = container.findAll('b')
    highway_number = search1[1].text

    location = list(container.p.descendants)[10]
    ID = my_url[my_url.find('?'):]
    mystr = ID.strip('?')

    query = "INSERT INTO table_name (ID, toll_name, location, highway_number) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
    data = (ID, toll_name, location, highway_number)

    cursor.execute(query, data)

# Commit the transaction
conn.commit()
```

Comment: i am getting this error while running the code 
`File "C:\Users\prash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "prashant" is not permitted to log in`

Comment: You need to alter role with login privileges.
 Can be done by following command: `ALTER ROLE "prashant" WITH LOGIN;`

Comment: Hi, can u check this please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025873/how-to-insert-scraped-table-data-into-postgresql-directly-python

Comment: Hi, Can u help me for finding this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052939/how-to-scrap-specific-datatoll-detail-between-source-and-destination