# Insert scraped table data directly into PostgreSQL db

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to insert my scraped data directly into PostgreSQL db, I'm struggling with writing query for this, any help would be appreciated.

The code I've came up with so far:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='--',user='--', password='--', port=--)
cursor = conn.cursor()
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236").read(),'lxml')
tbody = soup('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    writer.writerow(cols)
    print(cols)
```

My table's details are as follows:

```
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers
---------------+---------+-----------
 vehicle_type  | text    | not null
 one_time      | integer | not null
 return_trip   | integer |
 monthly_pass  | integer | not null
 local_vehicle | integer | not null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `cols` contains 5 elements, in order which you presented at your table, otherwise adjust indexes.

```
import csv
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='--', user='--', password='--', port='--')
cursor = conn.cursor()
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(
    "http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236").read(), 'lxml')
tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    if cols:
        vehicle_type = cols[0]
        one_time = int(cols[1])
        return_strip = int(cols[2])
        monthly_pass = int(cols[3])
        local_vehicle = int(cols[4])

        query = "INSERT INTO table_name (vehicle_type, return_strip, monthly_pass, local_vehicle) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
        data = (vehicle_type, one_time, return_strip, monthly_pass, local_vehicle)
        cursor.execute(query, data)

# Commit the transaction
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Hi, 
i am facing this issue
`vehicle_type = cols[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It means that your `cols` are empty and you haven't scrapped anything.

Comment: but when i was exporting in csv file all scraped data coming fine , here is the detail -
`Type of vehicle Single Journey Return Journey Monthly Pass Commercial Vehicle Registered within the district of plaza
Car/Jeep/Van 45 70 1565 25
    
LCV 75 115 2525 40
    
Bus/Truck 160 240 5290 80
    
Upto 3 Axle Vehicle 175 260 5770 85
    
4 to 6 Axle 250 375 8295 125
    
HCM/EME 250 375 8295 125
    
7 or more Axle 305 455 10100 150
`

Comment: here each time its taking empty `[ ]` , I tried to strip that using `.strip("[ ]")` but its not working ,

Comment: this is which i find when debugging

`>>> for row in tbody:
...     cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
...     [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
...
['Type of vehicle', 'Single Journey', 'Return Journey', 'Monthly Pass', 'Commercial Vehicle Registered within the district of plaza']
['Car/Jeep/Van', '45.00', '70.00', '1565.00', '25.00']
[]
['LCV', '75.00', '115.00', '2525.00', '40.00']
[]
['Bus/Truck', '160.00', '240.00', '5290.00', '80.00']
[]
['Upto 3 Axle Vehicle', '175.00', '260.00', '5770.00', '85.00']
[]
`

Comment: Every second column is empty, that's the problem. Take a look at my updated answer

Comment: ur answer is really very very helpful sir, thanks a lot!!!
I start learning python and web scrapping last 4 days ago. 
again thank u so mch.. :)

Comment: hi, can u plz check this , i tried since whole day, but did not get solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035185/how-to-extract-data-from-multiple-url-using-python

i have 4 to 493 url links