# How to extract data from multiple URL using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi i want to scrap data from multiple URL, I am doing like

```
for i in range(493):
    my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID={}'.format(i)
```

but it not giving me complete data, it is printing only last url data,

here is my code, plz help

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import psycopg2
import operator


for i in range(493):
    my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID={}'.format(i)

    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page1_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    # html parsing
    page1_soup = soup(page1_html, 'html.parser')

    # grabing data
    containers = page1_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'PA15'})

    # Make the connection to PostgreSQL
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='--',user='--', password='--', port=--)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for container in containers:
        toll_name1 = container.p.b.text
        toll_name = toll_name1.split(" ")[1]

        search1 = container.findAll('b')
        highway_number = search1[1].text.split(" ")[0]

        text = search1[1].get_text()
        onset = text.index('in')
        offset = text.index('Stretch')
        state = str(text[onset +2:offset]).strip(' ')

        location = list(container.p.descendants)[10]
        mystr = my_url[my_url.find('?'):]
        TID = mystr.strip('?TollPlazaID=')

        query = "INSERT INTO tollmaster (TID, toll_name, location, highway_number, state) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
        data = (TID, toll_name, location, highway_number, state)

        cursor.execute(query, data)

# Commit the transaction
conn.commit()
```

but it's displaying only second-last url data

Comment: your "format" statement generates only one url...

Comment: but i have so many other url's also , ex-
`http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=203
http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=258
` ,,
then how i have to do ?

Comment: I suppose sth like: `my_url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID={}'.format(i)`

Comment: still its throwing error
`   tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: check the error it says that you are trying to access an item that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like some of the pages are missing your key information, you can use `error-catching` for it, like this:

```
try: 
    tbody = soup('table', {"class": "tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
except IndexError:
    continue  # Skip this page if no items were scrapped
```

You may want to add some logging/print information to keep track of nonexisting tables.

EDIT: 
It's showing information from only last page, as you are commiting your transaction outside the `for` loop, overwriting your `conn` for every `i`. Just put `conn.commit()` inside `for` loop, at the far end.

Comment: hey sorry, that was the wrong code , plz have a look my update code , 
here only last url data is printing in table